# Monitoring bandwidth on a layer-3 invisible switch

Tags: monitoring, switch, snmp

Our servers are distributed to 2 racks in a datacenter, each rack having its own switch. The communication between the racks are made by the link between these two switches. The bandwidth between those switches is as low as '2 mbps', so our team lead rightfully suspects that might be a bottleneck so we want to monitor bandwidth usage between those two switches using SNMP.

The major problem is, switches are configured as completely layer-3 invisible, so there is no way to reach the switches using tcp/ip. How should I proceed?

Comment: Do the switches even support SNMP management?  What model of switch?

Comment: How fast is the link between the switches?  Half / Full Duplex?  How did you get the 2 Mb number?

Comment: Our team lead claims to be so.

Comment: again, simply knowing the make/model of switch will allow us to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

If the switches aren't manageable, then they aren't manageable and they will always be an unknown when trying to troubleshoot network issues.

If they *can* be managed, change their config so that you can monitor them via SNMP. If you don't have access to do this, work with your datacenter vendor or find a new one.

Comment: I have direct access to the said switch via serial port. It seems the switch is layer-3 aware but configured to be layer-3 transparent.

Comment: So change the configuration! If you want to monitor something via SNMP, it needs to be talking IP first.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean by layer3-aware but layer3-transparent. It's either operating as a layer3 switch or it isn't. If it isn't then it's operating as a layer 2 switch. A managed layer 2 switch will be ip address configurable and will have SNMP capability in order to monitor and manage it.